# Connected Spaces

Tags: general-topology

Let $\{X_\beta\}_{\beta \in J}$ be an indexed family of connected spaces, and let $X := \prod \limits_{\beta \in J} X_\beta$ with product topology. Fix $(\alpha_\beta)$ in $X$. Fix a finite subset $K$ of $J$ and let $X_K$ be the subspace of $X$ containing all $(x_\beta)$ in $X$ for which $x_\beta = \alpha_\beta$ if $\beta$ is not in $K$. Are the union $Y$ of all such spaces for all possible finite sets $K$ connected, and does this imply that $X$ is connected?

Comment: You may insert mathematical formulae on this site by enclosing LaTeX code in `$...$`. Also, please consider phrasing your posts as _questions_ rather than _orders_.

Comment: Do you know how to show that each $X_K$ is connected?

Comment: This looks like homework.  Please read http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Let $X$ be a space.

1. If $\{C_\alpha:\alpha\in J\}$ is a family of connected subsets of $X$ such that $\displaystyle\bigcap_{\alpha\in J}C_\alpha\ne\varnothing$, then $\displaystyle\bigcup_{\alpha\in J}C_\alpha$ is connected.
2. If $C\subseteq X$ is connected, so is $\operatorname{cl}_XC$.

Depending on what results you already have available, you may need to use (1) more than once.